# JMeter XPath Extractor SAXException

Tags: xpath, jmeter, jsoup

I am using xpath extractor to retrieve a form attribute value from the response data. However, this response data contains, among other data the String "C&I", and this is causing the following SAXException

> jmeter.extractor.XPathExtractor: SAXException  while processing
>   `(substring-after(//form[@id='headerForm']/@action,'/dashboard.xhtml?'))`
>   The reference to entity "I" must end with the ';' delimiter.

I do not have any control over this data since it is being obtained from the database. I tried checking the "Use Tidy(tolerant parser)" option. That results in the following warning/error

> ERROR - jmeter.util.XPathUtil: TidyException: line 35 column 31 -
>   Warning: trimming empty <div>

Line 35 of the response is as follows:

```
`<div style="clear: both;"></div>`
```

Extracting that attribute value is essential for further processing for me.

Answer (score 5):

As for everything there is solution, it might be quick and dirty but there is always more solutions to a single problem.

I recommend using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to do the parsing of HTML for you instead of xpath extractor. I'm assuming you're trying to extract the particular forms' action attribute.

Step 1 -> Add `jsoup-1.6.3.jar` or any other version to your `JMETER_HOME\lib`

Step 2 -> Add a `BeanShell PostProcessor` to your `Sampler` HTTP or any other

Step 3 -> In a Script big box paste this code :

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

String html = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); // get response from your sampler
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String formAction = doc.select("#headerForm").attr("action");
vars.put("action", formAction);
```

HTML selectors are jquery based. So it can do pretty nice and neat things. Anyway you should have `${action}` variable to use further in your tests.

**Update**

So you don't get tangled with the code I've created jMeter post processor called `Html Extractor` here is the github url :

https://github.com/c0mrade/Html-Extractor

Comment: Ant, Thank you for the response. However, when I doing prev.getRespon.... the html I get is not from the current request (The flow is index.xhtml->dashboard.xhtml). I need to extract the data from dashboard.xhtml. I added the JSoup code under the second HttpREquest corresponding to dashboard.xhtml. However, the html I am getting corresponds to index.xhtml. I tried curr.getREsponse... but that does not work. I could not find much help on the JSoup website. Could you pls help me resolve this. Thx, Karthik

Comment: are you reading from file called dashboard.xhtml? Can you please update your question with some additional info, i.e. proper structure, your testing flow, screenshots whatever that gives additional info. It's hard to understand when all is put into one sentence

Answer (score 1):

The stray `&` in your source document is not legal in XML. From the XML spec (emphasis mine)

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) may appear
>   in their literal form only when used as markup delimiters, or within a
>   comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. They are also
>   legal within the literal entity value of an internal entity
>   declaration; see "4.3.2 Well-Formed Parsed Entities". **If they are
>   needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character
>   references or the strings "*&amp*;" and "*&lt*;" respectively**.

The parser is interpreting the `&` as the start of an entity reference, which it expects to end with a semicolon.

Source:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210/#syntax

Note that the error you've included is (almost certainly) unrelated. Tidy is merely pointing out that the div contains no content (i.e. it's empty).