# How to properly use xpath & regexp extractor in jmeter?

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter

I have the following text in the HTML response:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="testValue">
```

I need to extract the value from the above input tag.
I've tried both regexp and xpath extractor, but neither is working for me:

- regexp pattern

  ```
  input\s*type="hidden"\s*name="test"\s*value="(.+)"\s*>
  ```
- xpath query

  ```
  //input[@name="test"]/@value
  ```

The above xpath gives an error at the Xpath Assertion Listener `.. "No node matched"`.

I tried a lot and concluded that the xpath works only if I use it as `//input[@name]`.

At the moment I'm trying to add an actual name it gives the error `.. "No node matched"`.

Could anyone please suggest me how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at my previous answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452267/169277

The relevant part for you would be step 3:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Element;

String html = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); // get response from your sampler
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element inputElement = doc.select("input[name=test]").first();
String inputValue = inputElement.attr("value");
vars.put("inputTextValue", inputValue);
```

**Update**

So you don't get tangled with the code I've created jMeter post processor called Html Extractor here is the github url :

https://github.com/c0mrade/Html-Extractor

Comment: Thanks for the beanShell example and the htmlExtractor +1

Comment: Just a small correction in BeanShell code on line 3: Replace line 3 with `import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XPath Extractor to parse HTML (not XML) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).

Your xpath query looks fine, check the option mentioned above and try again.